# std::unordered_map bucket index

Tags: c++

I have been assigned to return the index of the bucket containing a specific key in an std::unordered_map. Basically exactly what the bucket(key) function returns. I have tried creating an iterator to a bucket, but don't know if that is possible. I see that by using the begin() function, it returns an iterator to the first element of the container, but by adding a parameter it returns an iterator to the first element of a given bucket, hence the parameter is the index of the bucket. I'm just lost and don't know whether I'm actually getting at something.

Comment: _"hence the parameter is the index of the bucket"_ - no it is not - the parameter (argument) is any key - not an index.  The hash function is applied to that key, then the value returned by the hash function is typically (I don't think it's guaranteed) to be modded (i.e. operator `%`) into the current `.bucket_count()`.  If you wan to know the _index_ of the bucket where a key is - rather than get an iterator to it - you could hash the key and mod it by `.bucket_count()` yourself, then if you like - sanity check that `bucket(your_calculated_index)` returns the same iterator as `bucket(key)`.

Comment: The [`bucket`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/bucket) member return the specific bucket index for a specific key. You can use that index in conjunction with `begin(index)` and `end(index)` to iterate just that bucket. But I'm utterly lost on what you're actually trying to do. You say, "I have been assigned to return the index of the bucket containing a specific key in an std::unordered_map. Basically exactly what the bucket(key) function returns." - if it's exactly what `bucket(key)` returns, what exactly is the problem then?